# If case not working inside Widget [Flutter]

Tags: flutter

Can't I write if case inside Widget in order to choose which Container to show?

my code:

```
return Card(
          child: Container(
              child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              width: 50.0,
              height: 50.0,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  image: new DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      image: new NetworkImage(
                          hits[index]["b"]["c"])))),
          hits[index]["f"] == null
              ? Container(
                  child: Text("if"),
                )
              : Container(
                  child: Text("else"),
                )
        ],
      )));
```

When I do thing like up, it gives instant error.

Error:

> flutter: Another exception was thrown:
>   'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 213
>   pos 15: 'data != null': is not true.

Comment: "it gives instant error." seeing that error is essential for diagnosing the problem - so please add it to your question.

Comment: updated question

Comment: I don't know whether this error related to this or not, because the only error log i see is the one that I added to question

Comment: Yes, you can make conditional rendering, error seems not relevant to this code.

Comment: @HemanthRaj can u show an example as an answer?

Comment: Posted an example as answer, checked and that works for me. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work, you can make conditional rendering in flutter.

Example:

```
Card(
    child: Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 50.0,
            height: 50.0,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          data == null
              ? Container(
                  child: Text("if"),
                )
              : Container(
                  child: Text("else"),
                )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same thing

Comment: Thank u it worked, but I don't know why, since what I'm doing is same

Comment: problem is it is not entering to else state, since after iteration there a some things that is not null

Comment: Try calling setState